# How to write a set of lists to Excel using xlsxwriter (without pandas)?

Tags: python, excel, list, xlsxwriter

I created 3 separated lists and appended them into a empty.

I would like to write each list in Excel under the column `Company`, `Sector`, `URL`.

I tried to iterate them without success.

I'd like to do it without going through Pandas.

```
    import xlsxwriter

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('To add')

    companies = ['House1', 'House2']
    sector = ['Kitchen', 'Living room']
    url = ['www.house1.com', 'www.house2.com']

    list_companies = []
    list_companies.append(companies)
    list_companies.append(sector)
    list_companies.append(url)

    head = ['Company', 'Sector', 'URL']
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold':True})

    worksheet.write_row(0,0,head, bold)
    workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way is probably to use the `write_column()` method. Like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('To add')

companies = ['House1', 'House2']
sector = ['Kitchen', 'Living room']
url = ['http://www.house1.com', 'http://www.house2.com']

head = ['Company', 'Sector', 'URL']
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold':True})

# Make some of the columns wider for clarity.
worksheet.set_column(0, 1, 12)
worksheet.set_column(2, 2, 20)

# Write the data.
worksheet.write_row(0,0,head, bold)
worksheet.write_column(1, 0, companies)
worksheet.write_column(1, 1, sector)
worksheet.write_column(1, 2, url)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Note, I added `http://` to the urls so that they are converted by XlsxWriter to Excel links.

For writing data with XlsxWriter see the [Working with and Writing Data](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_data.html) section of the XlsxWriter docs.

Comment: thanks, I think this solution is more simple for me to understand.

Comment: I just tried worksheet.set_column(0, 1, 12) but it has no effect on the cells. Can you explain why you used it two times? Thanks.

Comment: It changes the column width (and other properties if required). It is called twice to set 2 different widths for 2 different ranges. It is just there to make the output clearer. It isn't required. See here for an explanation: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-column

Answer (score 1):

Converted lists aggregation to a dictionary for convenience.

To write to excel use the [`worksheet.write(row, col, *args)`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html) as follows:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('To add')

companies = ['House1', 'House2']
sectors = ['Kitchen', 'Living room']
urls = ['www.house1.com', 'www.house2.com']

companies_dictionary = {}

companies_dictionary['companies']   = companies
companies_dictionary['sector']      = sectors
companies_dictionary['url']         = urls

head = ['Company', 'Sector', 'URL']
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

worksheet.write_row(0, 0, head, bold)


head_offset = 1
for company_index in range(len(companies_dictionary['companies'])):
    current_excel_row_number = company_index + head_offset + 1
    worksheet.write(f'A{current_excel_row_number}', companies_dictionary['companies'][company_index])
    worksheet.write(f'B{current_excel_row_number}', companies_dictionary['sector'][company_index])
    worksheet.write(f'C{current_excel_row_number}', companies_dictionary['url'][company_index])

workbook.close()
```

Result:

```
Company Sector  URL
House1  Kitchen www.house1.com
House2  Living room www.house2.com
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Why it has go through rows_number = len(companies) ? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Welcome @Steven. It's a good way to keep track of the current company being written, assuming all details regarding the companies are the same length it's the right way to go.